# How do install Chello?

Tags: c#, dll, nuget

This is an embarrassingly simple question...

How do I use Chello? If I go to https://bitbucket.org/mrshrinkray/chello/src I can see all the solution files. Is there a way to download as a DLL and just include it in my project? Is there a NuGet package for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link on the homepage here:

https://bitbucket.org/mrshrinkray/chello/overview

To the zip file containing examples etc.

https://bitbucket.org/mrshrinkray/chello/get/d6eef8794afd.zip

Download it, unzip the file, Add the Chello.Core project to the same level as your existing projects.

Right-click your solution and choose add existing project, select the Chello.Core.csproj.

In the project that uses Chello, add your appsettings for authkey and token:

```
<add key="AuthKey" value="YourAuthKey" />
<add key="AuthToken" value="YourAuthToken" />
```

Unfortunately I don't think there is a nugget package.

Comment: Cheers - had to click on Enable NuGet Package Restore to make it work as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133854/opening-project-in-visual-studio-fails-due-to-nuget-targets-not-found-error but worked great after that

Answer (score 1):

Open your solution in Visual Studio, right-click on the solution, "Add existing project" -> select the downloaded Chello project as a "class library".

I may have rearranged the order of actions - not having access to VS right now.