# Nuget.target was not found error, when adding existing project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have a newly created project on visual studio 2015. I have separate project which I am trying to add(import) to my existing one, when I click add I get an error that reads something like "C:\ProjectFolderPath\nuget\nuget.targets" was not found. I have tried adding this by righ-clicking on the solution and click add existing project, also tried clicking file->project/soluction then checking the add-to-solution radio button, but I still get the same error.

I have tried enable package restore, but still no joy. I am using TFS and no commit has been recorded as yet(not sure if this might be the cause). The project that I'm trying to add its just a DAL project then the one that I want to add to, is an MVC web app

Note: the path used in the question is just an example, its not literally ProjectFolderPath

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening project in Visual Studio fails due to nuget.targets not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133854/opening-project-in-visual-studio-fails-due-to-nuget-targets-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not a solution per se, its just a workaround, since I have two version of VS(2015 and 2013) installed, I tried enable the package restore using the 2013 version it worked fine, then open the 2015 and reloaded the project, all is well now, I however believe there should be a solution of V2015 as well